# Запятые при обращении

Tags: пунктуация

"Ну Ваня, зачем ты это сделал?" - мне кажется, что нужно поставить запятую перед "Ваня", т.к. это обращение, но интонационно при этом они считаются единым целом. Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово ***НУ***  может выражать нетерпение,  побуждение к действию, призыв к вниманию (если далее следует рассказ о чем-то). Во всех случаях НУ может относиться к обращению **к качестве усилительной частицы,** а может обособляться как **междометие**.

Выбор варианта зависит от ситуации и проверяется **по наличию паузы и по ударению**, которое падает на междометие и не падает на частицу.

(1)  ***Ну ВАня, отвечай же,  зачем ты это сделал?***  Это побуждение к тому, чтобы наконец-то получить от Вани ответ.  Паузы перед обращением  нет, частица безударная.

(2) ***Ну, Ваня, отвечай! Зачем  ты это сделал?*** Это тоже побуждение к действию, но слово НУ выделено ударением (то есть сначала выражено побуждение, а уже потом обозначено само действие). Фраза звучит более категорично.

Примеры:

1) **НУ (междометие, призыв к вниманию, произношение с паузой)**

1) Иван Тимофеевич понял, что теперь пропал окончательно, и, пригласив к себе Чонкина, выставил две бутылки чистейшего первача. ― **Ну, Ваня,** ― сказал он почти радостно, ― теперь нам с тобой крышка. ― А в чем дело? ― поинтересовался Чонкин. [Владимир Войнович.(1969-1975)]

2) **НУ (частица, выражение просьбы, нет паузы)**

Меня пока никто не приглашал,  – ответил он. –  **Ну Виталий Николаевич**,  – взмолился Дзюба,  – ну пожалуйста ... [Александра Маринина. (2014)]

Answer (score 1):

Да. Обращения всегда выделяются запятыми.

Исключение в данном случае может быть  только если Ну является частью обращения (фамилия, звание и т.д.). Скорее всего это междометие, поэтому запятая нужна.

И, как исключение

> Если междометие О в предложении стоит перед обращением, то запятая или
>   восклицательный знак между междометием и обращением не ставится:
>
> Не прав твой, о небо, святой приговор (Лермонтов)

[Грамота](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_180)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, в приведённом примере (вопросе) запятая после "ну" не ставится.

Вот этот случай в классике:

> Ну бал! **Ну Фамусов!** умел гостей назвать!
>
> Какие-то уроды с того света,
>
> И не с кем говорить, и не с кем танцевать.

Правило:

[Если междометие «ну» выражает удивление, восхищение или недовольство, негодование, иронию, то оно не обособляется.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_501)

Comment: "Ну Фамусов!" это же не обращение, а речь о Фамусове в третьем лице.